# ARM64 Ubuntu desktop on QEMU

Tags: qemu, arm64

I am trying to run ubuntu desktop in a QEMU arm VM.
I have tried this in both windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 and cant get it to work.

""
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 4g -cpu cortex-a72 -smp 4 -M virt -bios QEMU_EFI.fd -drive if=none,file=ubuntu-desktop-arm64.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -drive file=user-data.img,format=raw
""
run the above and get this [image: QEMU Display][image: Shell output]

i can start heedlessly with the below command
""
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 4g -cpu cortex-a72 -smp 4 -M virt -nographic -bios QEMU_EFI.fd -drive if=none,file=ubuntu-desktop-arm64.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -drive file=user-data.img,format=raw
""
above based on https://gist.github.com/billti/d904fd6124bf6f10ba2c1e3736f0f0f7

I had some success in Linux running a raspberry PI following the approach here https://azeria-labs.com/emulate-raspberry-pi-with-qemu/

but i don't have a kernel to swap out for ubuntu, also don't know what changes are made by this kernel swap, i know it sets a min Driver size and a 256k Ram size but know little more then that